# Is there a secure two party protocol that $P_1$ (with x as input) gets $rx+r'$ and $P_2$ gets $(r,r')$

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, protocol-design, multiparty-computation

It should be a secure two party protocol against a malicious adversary.

$P_1$'s input is $X$ in $Z_p^*$ (p is a prime number);
$P_2$'s input is nothing.
$P_1$'s output is $r_X+r'$, where $r$,$r'$ are random numbers from $Z_p^*$
$P_2$' output is $r$ and $r'$.

Is there any efficient protocol to realize this functionality other than by using homomorphic encryption?
If only HE solves this problem, which is the most efficient one?

Thanks for help!

Comment: This is a well-known problem called Oblivious Linear function Evaluation (OLE).

Comment: Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This functionality can be instantiated using OLE (oblivious linear function evaluation). In a standard OLE, Alice gets (r, r'), Bob gets (x, y=rx+r'), where Alice picks r and Bob picks x. But if you want r to be random then you can just sample it from the uniform distribution.

OLE can be implemented very efficiently using lattices or OT. Here is one example: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/970

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any additive/logarithmically homomorphic scheme with $p$ dividing the order of the plaintext group. The [Okamoto-Uchiyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okamoto%E2%80%93Uchiyama_cryptosystem) system has plaintext space size exactly $p$ and may be suitable if you have no quantum resistance required.

The protocol is as follows:

P1 creates a public key for the scheme as well as encryptions of $X$ and 1, say $c_0=E(X)$ and $c_1=E(1)$. These are passed to P2.

Assuming a log-homomorphic scheme, P2 chooses random $r$ and $r’$, computes $c_2:=c_0^rc_1^{r’}=E(rX+r’)$ and sends this value to P1.

P1 decrypts $c_2$ to recover $rX+r’$.

Comment: thank you! how about its efficiency compared with the Paillier scheme? I want an efficient one because I want it be secure against malicious adversary.  Do you know any method other than   HE?

Comment: And I also want a random r and r', but in your scheme, r and r' are decided by P2 which could be malicious.

Comment: O-U is similar in efficiency to Paillier, and often more efficient for the same level of security. I don’t know of any non-HE solution.

Comment: To defend against malicious P2, P1 can choose random $s1$ and $s2$ and form $(r+s1)X+(r’+s2)$. Sending $s1$ and $s2$ to P2 allows them to form $r+s1$ and $r’+s2$

Comment: Thanks! I will study O-U scheme. But i thinks to make it secure, some additonal ZKP may have to be added; things like proving the public parameter is rightly generated etc.